# Regular expression- TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, regex

This is pat of data I have

```
 'E10641',
 'Type 1 diabetes mellitus with ',
 'hypoglycemia with coma',
 'E1110',
 'Type 2 diabetes mellitus with ketoacidosis ',
 'without coma',
 'E1100',
 'Type 2 diabetes mellitus with ',
 'hyperosmolarity withoutnonketotic ',
 'hyperglycemic-hyperosmolar coma ',
 '(NKHHC)',
 'E1111',
 'Type 2 diabetes mellitus with ketoacidosis ',
 'with coma',
 'Diabetes short-term complications diagnosis codes: (ACDIASD)',
 'June 2018',
 '3 of 3',
```

I am trying to write a regular expression code to extract codes start with "E" and follows by numbers, such as E10641.

```
This is my program:
import re
content = str(content)
for line in content:
    if len (line>0):
        x = re.search("E[0-9]+", content)
        print (x)
```

But it has the following error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I fixed the problem by editing the section if `len (line)>0` as suggested in the answer to this question. This is the updated version of the code:

```
import re
ICD = []

#content = str(content)
for line in content:
    if len (line) >0 :
        x = re.search("E[0-9]+", content)
        ICD = ICD.append(x)
        print (x)
```

I need to extract all the codes and put them in a list. But now I have the following error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: `if len(line)>0:`

Comment: `if len(line)` works same as `if len(line)>1`

Comment: @SEDaradji `>= 1` or `>0`

Comment: `>=` 1 and  `>0` are the same thing

Comment: @SEDaradji Yes, and neither is the same as `> 1`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `if len(line):` is equivalent to `if len(line) != 0`, but since `len` won't (well, shouldn't) return a negative number, we could relax it to `len(line) > 0`. However, there's no reason to even all `len`, as `if line:` is true for any non-empty string. (And further still, given that `content` is a `str`, `line` is *guaranteed* to be a single-character string as long as it gets set at all.)

Comment: `content = str(content)` is probably not what you want; it's not clear what `content` is to begin with, but I assume it is a *list* of strings, as it seems like `line` is intended to be one of the strings from the original file.

Comment: @chepner, I added content = str(content) to covert all data to string. Bu it did not solve the problem. The original file is a pdf file that was split to lines using (\n)

Comment: @Mary Then each element of that list *is* a `str`, and you want to iterate over that list. Given `n = [1,2,3]`, compare `str(n)` with `[str(x) for x in n]`. You are creating the former where you want the latter.

Comment: for line in content if line: is also possible

Comment: @chepner, thank you for your suggestion, I updated the code, would you please take a look?

Comment: You probably also want to pass `line` to `re.search`, and check the value of `x` rather than unconditionally adding it to `ICD`; see the documentation for `re.search`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are trying to do, but the problem is in this line 
`if len (line>0):` you are checking if a string is bigger than an int, and you are asking what the length of that answer is.

I'm guessing you wanted to type `if len(line)>0:` and you dont need to check if its bigger than 0, you can just use `if line:`
an empty string is False while a nonempty string is True

```
>>> a="sss"
>>> b=""
>>> bool(a)
True
>>> bool(b)
False
```

Comment: I updated the code according to your suggestion, but now there is another problem. Please see.

Comment: (1) Don’t use parentheses around an `if` condition in Python: they are unnecessary clutter. (2) `if line` is *a lot less clear* than `if len(line) > 0`. Remember the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): *Explicit is better than implicit.*

Comment: @KonradRudolph seems my java is leaking

Comment: @Mary you cant assing the apply method, it does not return anything.
so just replace: `ICD = ICD.append(x)` with `ICD.append(x)`